# Elementary Loki GUI Volume Reduce is not working

Tags: release-loki, audio

The Sounds Panel in the System Settings does not show any of my speakers. Also, using the GUI to adjust the volume does not work at all.

However, the speakers work and applications can actually play audio. Trying to adjust the volume through `alsamixer` works, though.

Here is what details I have about my audio device using `lspci`

`00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` did the trick for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then, if necessary:

`sudo alsa force-reload`

and

`reboot`